# WebDriver Ruby binding: How to specify Firefox binary path in code?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2

I'm writing my test cases in Windows7 with Ruby (v1.9.3-p194).

Please, note that I want to specify Firefox binary path when using RemoteWebDriver, not FirefoxDriver.

Here is the command line I used to start Selenium server 2.25.0:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar
```

And here is the Ruby code I used to initialize webdriver in my test suite:

```
@capa = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox
@capa[:firefox_binary] = "D:\FirefoxStuff\FF13.0.1\firefox.exe"
@remote_server_url = "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, {:url => @remote_server_url, :desired_capabilities => @capa})
```

However when I execute the test case, an error says 
`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH.`
So, it's obvious my binary path specification is not working.

Does anybody know how to achieve that besides setting my PATH?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at this too. Seems there is a bit of problem in as_json in Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities

firefox_binary get's re-written to firefoxBinary in the json call to webdriver grid, this means that the binary you have supplied does not register as it's assigned to the wrong key.

Chaning:

```
def as_json(opts = nil)
      hash = {}

      @capabilities.each do |key, value|
        case key
        when :platform
          hash['platform'] = value.to_s.upcase
        when :firefox_profile
          hash['firefox_profile'] = value.as_json['zip'] if value
        when :proxy
          hash['proxy'] = value.as_json if value
        when String
          hash[key] = value
        when Symbol
          hash[camel_case(key.to_s)] = value
        else
          raise TypeError, "expected String or Symbol, got #{key.inspect}:#{key.class} / #{value.inspect}"
        end
      end

      hash
    end
```

to

```
def as_json(opts = nil)
      hash = {}

      @capabilities.each do |key, value|
        case key
        when :platform
          hash['platform'] = value.to_s.upcase
        when :firefox_profile
          hash['firefox_profile'] = value.as_json['zip'] if value
        when :proxy
          hash['proxy'] = value.as_json if value
        when :firefox_binary
          hash['firefox_binary'] = value
        when String
          hash[key] = value
        when Symbol
          hash[camel_case(key.to_s)] = value
        else
          raise TypeError, "expected String or Symbol, got #{key.inspect}:#{key.class} / #{value.inspect}"
        end
      end

      hash
    end
```

Seems to work.